# Exporting types and enums fails when using yarn/npm link

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, npm-link, yarn-link

I'm trying to link a library between two projects to help with development workflow.
Sharing some code and types between my TypeScript backend and frontend.

It seemed to work with const functions, but when I add some enums and types I get this error:

```
./server/presenter-common/src/events.ts 5:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:7)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| 
| 
> export enum SESSION_STATUS{
|     SCHEDULED="SCHEDULED",
|     LIVE="LIVE",
```

My code:

```
export enum SESSION_STATUS{
    SCHEDULED="SCHEDULED",
    LIVE="LIVE",
    ENDED="ENDED",
    RUNNING="RUNNING"
}
```

It works on my server app (TypeScript, ExpressJs).

But fails on react frontend (un-ejected create-react-app).

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you solved it?

Comment: Sorry to say that I really don't remember. I think not.